# Calculating Odds Ratios from R output

Tags: self-study, generalized-linear-model, odds-ratio

I've fitted a GLM with a binomial link function in R, and need to interpret the result of the fit.

How do I calculate the Odds Ratio for country 2 relative to country 1? Also, how do I calculate the Odds Ratio for country 2 relative to country 3?

￼[image: Here is the R output]

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you mean, but does `exp(fm)` give you the information you need (replace "`fm`" with whatever your model is called)?

Comment: @smillig - apologies if my original post wasn't clear. here is everything given in the question: http://i.imgur.com/Juo7PPy.png 

and the full question is:
Calculate the odds-ratio for Norway relative to Finland and for Norway relative to Sweden.

thanks so much for your help

Comment: In case it wasn't clear, this is from a written exam so the answer would preferably be written on paper, not using R commands